# How to keep or drop LVM snapshot?

Tags: linux, lvm, snapshot

I have made an LVM snapshop by

```
lvcreate --name snap --size 10G -s /dev/vg00/vm
```

What command should I write if I want to drop the snapshot, and not keep the changes that have happened since the snapshot?

And what command should I write to roll the changes from the snapshot into /dev/vg00/vm ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

to drop snapshot use:

```
lvremove group/snap-name
```

to merge snapshot use:

```
lvconvert --merge group/snap-name
```

Though merging will be deferred until the orgin and snapshot volumes are unmounted. You may need to update kernel (>=2.6.33) and lvm tools to have support for merging.

Comment: Does this mean that you can run `lvconvert --merge ...` then reboot in order to rewind the volume?

Comment: @Hubro Exactly. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LVM#Snapshots for more information

Comment: I've just lost data following this advice because LVM terminology is backwards IMO. Correct me if I'm wrong, by when LVM says "drop a snapshot", it means merging the changes from the COW volume into the origin volume, and "merge a snapshot" means reverting the origin volume to the state when the snapshot was made, effectively dropping the changes stored in the COW volume.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this has been asked before:

[Linux LVM snapshot commit or revert?](https://serverfault.com/questions/128878/linux-lvm-snapshot-commit-or-revert)

As well as:

http://www.jonnor.com/2010/02/lvm-snapshot-merging-avaliable/

Comment: Ok, so `lvremove` accepts the changes in the snapshot. So far so good =)

Answer (score 3):

OK, first of all: the grand old LVM1 supported only read-only snapshots. In that case the modifications were copied to original image after unmounting the snapshot. LVM2 provides support for read-write snapshots, allowing you to do funkier stuff with virtual machine images and stuff like that.

Novell has a [very niece piece of documentation](https://www.suse.com/c/rollback-sles-online-updates-lvm-snapshots/) about the concept of using LVM for rolling back a failed OS update. Take a look at that article, it provides all the bits and pieces you need for your case.

Comment: So there isn't a command to drop the snapshot without accepting the changes?

Answer (score 2):

you can use lvremove command to remove the old snapshot files:

lvremove /dev/vg_brcvhost1/snap
this will ask you to remove a sanpshot persent in the your LV.

other commands are also there for managing a LVM based  VM setup.

you can find the details commands in the link below:
http://linux.math.tifr.res.in/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html

and the below link may also be usefull:
http://dentarg.it64.com/content/lvm-based-backup-virtual-machines

Answer (score 1):

I've just lost data following the selected answer to this question, so I'm posting this to clarify. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

IMO, LVM terminology is backwards. For reference [redhat's documentation to LVM snapshot](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_logical_volumes/snapshot-of-logical-volumes_configuring-and-managing-logical-volumes#merging-snapshot-to-its-original-volume_snapshot-of-logical-volumes)

When LVM says "drop a snapshot", it means merging the changes from the COW volume into the origin volume.

When LVM says "merge a snapshot", it means reverting the origin volume to the state when the snapshot was made, effectively dropping the changes stored in the COW volume.

I find this VERY counterintuitive, lost 43h of data because of that. Don't do the same mistake I did !

EDIT: OK now I understand my mistake. From the documentation:

> When you modify the original volume (the origin) after you take a snapshot, the snapshot feature makes a copy of the modified data area as it was prior to the change so that it can reconstruct the state of the volume. When you create a snapshot, full read and write access to the origin stays possible.

I wrongly assumed that LVM operated by freezing the origin partition and mounting the snapshot as an overlay to store the modifications, but this sentence makes it clear it does **not** work that way.